# cpp_doxygen not installing with vundle

Tags: vim

when I run :PluginInstall I get an error saying :Helptags could not processes ~/.vim/bundle/cpp_doxygen/doc I am however able to run :help cpp_doxygen and I do get it to open however when I press the shortcut to create a comment nothing happens here is my .vimrc

```
set nocompatable
filetype off
set rtp +=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
"Let vundle manage vundle
Plugin 'gmaric/vundle'
Plugin 'cpp_doxygen'
Plugin 'valloric/youcompleteme'
"let g_ycm_global_extra_conf = '~/.vim/.ycm_extra_conf.py
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plugin 'scrooloose/syntastic'
"set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
"set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatusLineFlag()}
"set statusline+=%*
"let g:syntastic_c_checkers = []
"let g:syntastic_cpp_checkers = []
"let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
"let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
"let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
Plugin 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
" install indent guides
Plugin 'kien/rainbow_parentheses.vim'
Plugin 'octol/vim-cpp-enhanced-highlight'
Plugin 'fsharp/vim-fsharp'
call vundle#end
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%*
let g:syntastic_c_checkers = []
let g:syntastic_cpp_checkers = []
let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0
let g:ycm_global_extra_conf = '~/.vim/.ycm_extra_conf.py'
let g:ycm_add_preview_to_completeopt = 1
let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_insertion = 1
let g:ycm_key_detailed_diagnostics = '<leader>D'
```

Comment: is it possibly supposed to be `Plugin 'vim-scripts/cpp_doxygen'`?

Comment: I've tried changing it to that and then tried :PluginInstall and I'm still getting the :helptags cannot process  ~/.vim/bundle/cpp_doxygen/doc